# como sumar N minutos al timestamp, javascript?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

Actualmente estoy obteniendo el timestamp de la fecha actual, a dicho timestamp, podre sumarle N minutos, es decir para obtener tiempo al sumarle por ejemplo diez minutos.

Ejemplo:
Obtener el timestap para la hora: 11:00 a.m
a dicho timestap sumarle 10 minutos, el resultado final seria: 11:10 a.m

Lo estoy realizando de la siguiente forma, pero sin resultado alguno.

```js
 let horario_firebase =  Date.now();//Valor en timestap
 let tiempo = 60;
 let ultima_fecha_vencimiento = horario_firebase+tiempo; 
 console.log("FECHA LUEGO DE HABER SUMADO LOS MINUTOS");
 console.log(horario_firebase);
 console.log(tiempo);
 console.log(ultima_fecha_vencimiento);
```

De antemano muchas gracias, bendiciones.

Comment: intentastes algo como `horario_firebase .setMinutes( horario_firebase .getMinutes() + tiempo );`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sencillo puedes usar esta funcion:

```js
const agregaMinutos =  function (dt, minutos) {
    return new Date(dt.getTime() + minutos*60000);
}
    console.log(agregaMinutos(new Date(2014,10,2), 30).toString());
```